# Filter date and time in Google Sheets Query

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, filter, stock-data

I use a formula like this to get stock data:

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol=IBM&interval=15min&slice=year1month1&apikey=demo")
```

Basically my goal is to filter the data by date and time with a query formula, so the table with the raw data does not show up.

I want the data from Column 1, Column 3 and Column 6, filtered by date (in this case 7/12/2022 from cell J1) and time (between 4:15:00 and 9:30:00).

I tried this formula

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol=IBM&interval=15min&slice=year1month1&apikey=demo"),"select Col1, Col3, Col6 WHERE Col1 > datetime '"&TEXT(J1+time(4,15,0),"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' and Col1 <= datetime '"&TEXT(J1+time(9,30,0),"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'")
```

but the only result I can get are the headers.

Here is a link to the [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mjuCnzvkfwMXZGWcvs1QqdYNpUtpMF9NjjnQD5AQz-k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: First thing i can tell you is that if you use the IMPORTDATA function, you'll likely hit your daily quota from Alphavantage by around 11am.

Comment: Doesn't the stock market open at 930? it makes sense there would be no IBM data before 930 am

Comment: I use another provider with unlimited date limit, I just used alphavantage in this example beacuse of the easy to use demo api.

Comment: Yes, the general stock market opens at 9:30 but there is pre market trading starting at 4:00, lasting until 9:30 and thats the time window where I need the data from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol=IBM&interval=15min&slice=year1month1&apikey=demo"),"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col6 WHERE Col1 > "&J1+TIME(4,15,0)&" AND Col1 <= "&J1+TIME(9,30,0))
```

For easier reading, here is the second argument of `=QUERY` isolated.

```
"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col6 WHERE Col1 > "&J1+TIME(4,15,0)&" AND Col1 <= "&J1+TIME(9,30,0)
```

### Explanation

Behind the scenes, all date and time values in Google Sheets are stored as simple numbers. Therefore, simple number comparison can be used in a query to determine if one date is greater than another, skipping a lot of the in-between with the `=TEXT` function and the `datetime` argument. The provided `=QUERY` simply compares each value in `Col1` to the sum of `J1` and your provided time value.

Functions used:

- [=QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [=IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en)
- [=TIME](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093056?hl=en)